# Wird Deutsch auch außerhalb von Deutschland, Österreich und der Schweiz gesprochen?

Tags: history, regional

Wird Deutsch auch außerhalb von Deutschland, Österreich und der Schweiz gesprochen?
Wobei ich natürlich nicht zwei Deutsche im Urlaub meine, sondern eine deutliche Verbreitung.

Comment: Ja, auf Mallorca.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ja, zum Beispiel in [Südtirol](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCdtirol). Das liegt in Nordostitalien und ist zufällig meine Heimat. Dort leben rund 350.000 deutschsprachige Menschen.

In [Liechtenstein](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liechtenstein) und [Luxemburg](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxemburg) ist Deutsch Amtssprache. In [Namibia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namibia) ist Deutsch eine der Nationalsprachen des Landes.

Es gibt noch weitere Länder, in denen deutschsprachige Minderheiten leben; dazu zählen [Dänemark](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Minderheit_in_D%C3%A4nemark), [Belgien](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschsprachige_Minderheiten#Belgien), [Polen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Minderheit_in_Polen) und [Rumänien](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rum%C3%A4niendeutsche).

Auf Wikipedia gibt es eine vollständige Aufzählung aller deutschsprachigen Minderheiten, die in Gebieten außerhalb Deutschlands, Österreichs, der Schweiz: [Deutschsprachige Minderheiten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschsprachige_Minderheiten).

Ein Abfrage bei Wolfram Alpha mit dem Begriff "[German language](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=german%20language)" ergibt übrigens folgende Angaben:

- total number of speakers: 127 million people (1.9% of world population, rank: 13th)
- total number of native speakers: 95.82 million people

Hier ist eine Karte, auf der die heutige Verbreitung der deutschen Sprache in Europa markiert ist:

[image: Verbreitung der deutschen Sprache; Quelle: Wikipedia]

*Quelle: [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datei:Verbreitungsgebiet_der_deutschen_Sprache.PNG&filetimestamp=20100518171910)*

Comment: @max danke für den Tipp. Hast du eine Quelle? Auf Wikipedia steht: "Amtssprache: Englisch; Nationalsprachen: Deutsch, Afrikaans, Oshivambo, Kwanyama, Ndonga, RuKwangali, Herero, Lozi und Khoekhoegowab"

Comment: Luxemburg nicht vergessen. Hab erst letztes Jahr erstaunt festgestellt, dass man da nicht (nur) Französisch spricht.

Comment: Namibias einzige Amtssprache ist Englisch (lt. Verfassung,http://www.un.int/wcm/content/site/namibia/pid/5185). Deutsch als Amtssprache gibt es nach Wikipedia (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Amtssprachen) zumindest gebietsweise in Belgien, Dänemark, Deutschland, Italien, Liechtenstein, Luxemburg, Österreich, Schweiz, Slowakei, Vatikanstadt.

Comment: @Mrmfldmn: splattne hat nicht behauptet, dass Deutsch in Namibia eine *Amts*sprache sei, sondern eine *National*sprache. Das ist etwas anderes. Siehe: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Sprachen_in_Namibia

Answer (score 6):

Im Elsass und in Lothringen in Frankreich (alsace et lorraine) wird auch recht viel Deutsch gesprochen. War im letzten Urlaub etwas überrascht, da wollten wir Wein kaufen, und die französische Dame hat uns alles in fließendem Deutsch erklärt.

Answer (score 6):

Deutsch ist Amtssprache in Belgien, Deutschland, Italien (Trentino-Südtirol), Liechtenstein, Luxemburg, Österreich, in der Schweiz und in der Slowakei (in der Gemeinde Krahule). In Polen wird Deutsch seit 1991 als eine der nationalen Minderheitensprachen anerkannt. Deutsch wird seit 1958 als Amtssprache der Europäischen Union (damals noch "Europäische Wirtschaftsgemeinschaft") anerkannt (siehe "Verordnung Nr. 1 zur Regelung der Sprachenfrage für die Europäische Wirtschaftsgemeinschaft", Amtsblatt Nr. 017 vom 6. Oktober 1958).

Deutsch wird auch noch als Regionalsprache anerkannt in der Region Elsass und im lothringischen Département Moselle (Frankreich), als Nationalsprache in Namibia, als offizielle Zweitsprache in den autonomen Mennonitenkolonien in Paraguay und als Verkehrs- und Verwaltungssprache der Deutschen Minderheit in Nordschleswig (Dänemark).

Deutsch ist auch eine anerkannte Minderheitensprache in Brasilien, Italien, Rumänien, Russland, der Slowakei, Tschechien, Ungarn und Südafrika.

Comment: Hm, das steht doch alles schon in splattnes Antwort, oder übersehe ich gerade was?

Comment: @Robert Wo eine bestimmte Sprache gesprochen wird und wo sie als Amtssprache anerkannt ist, ist eigentlich nicht das gleiche. (Und Splattne hat Brasilien nicht erwähnt.)

Answer (score 5):

Nicht nur in Europa. In Südbrasilien, spricht man [Riograndensisch oder Katharinensisch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riograndenser_Hunsr%C3%BCckisch)

Answer (score 4):

German is pretty strong in the "Bible Belt" of Southern Manitoba which stretches through the small towns of Steinbach, Morden and Winkler (population about 10,000 each) and the nearby countryside. The mostly Low German speakers include traditional Mennonites, recent Mennonite returnees from the Paraguay/Mexico emigrations of the early 20th century, recent German immigrants from Europe sponsored by the thriving local manufacturing industry, and Hutterites (basically Amish people who believe in machinery) living on their own colonies.

The big-city Mennonites of Winnipeg basically live and work in English, but in industries they dominate such as furniture manufacturing, windows and doors etc, many of the maintenance mechanics are drawn from the German-speaking small-town Bible Belt population.

Answer (score 1):

In der Mitte des 19. Jahrhunderts wanderen viele Deutsche nach Brasilien aus. Die meisten siedelten sich im Süden des Landes an, da dort das Klima passend ist. Es gibt dort auch Einwanderer aus der Schweiz. In manchen Orten können alle Bewohner Deutsch, z. B. In *Pomerode* im Bundesstaat Santa Catarina. In den Bundesstaaten Santa Catarina und Rio Grande do Sul gibt es viele Brasilianer mit Familiennamen deutscher Herkunft. Weiterhin gibt es im Süden Brasiliens auch Einwohner mit Schweizer Herkunft.

Answer (score -4):

Siehe [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Sprache#Verbreitung_und_rechtlicher_Status). Die deutsche Sprache ist recht weit verbreitet, wobei es hauptsächlich in Westeuropa gesprochen wird.

Comment: nur "siehe Wikipedia" ist nicht so schön. Dann lieber die Länder namentlich nennen, in denen die Sprache einen bestimmten Status hat. Dazu noch Quelle mit der umfassenderen Antwort zu verlinken, und schon gäb's ein upvote ;-)

Comment: @mbx Dann gib es doch splattne. Ich hab gerade nicht die Zeit lange Antworten zu schreiben. Und wofür Dinge wiederholen, die woanders gut aufbereitet verfügbar sind?