# Ist "Südlandslust" ein echtes Wort? Gibt es ein echtes Wort für diese Idee?

Tags: single-word-request, terminology

Ich halte die "Südlandslust" für ein deutsches Phänomen.

Damit meine ich eine Sehnsucht nach Spanien, Italien, Griechenland, usw.

Ist es ein richtiges Wort? Wenn nicht: Gibt es ein ähnliches, echtes Wort für diese Idee?

**English Translation:** I use the word  "Südlandslust" to describe a German phenomenon: That is a longing for Spain, Italian, Greece, etc.

Is this a real word? If not, what is a similar, genuine word for this idea?

Comment: M.W. war Goethe ein starker Italienfan. Ebenso ist mir Gottfried Benn als Freund des Mediterranen aufgefallen (`mir geschah die Olive`). Vielleicht findet man da was. Kritisch auseinandergesetzt hat sich damit, wenn ich mich recht erinnere, Rolf-Dieter Brinkmann (`Rom, Blicke`), der ein Stipendium oder etwas derartiges in der Villa Massimo gewonnen hatte.

Comment: Das ist eine Komposition, kein Neologismus. Daher würde ich es nicht als "richtiges Wort" im Sinne deiner Frage bezeichnen.

Comment: Wenn die Südlandlust ein deutsches Phänomen ist, bin ich kein Deutscher, denn mich packt stets die Nordlandlust ;)

Comment: Es gibt kein Echtwortkomitee. Selbstverständlich ist Südland(s)lust ein echtes Wort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das Wort habe ich noch nie gehört. Ich zweifle auch sehr stark, dass es existiert.

Das ähnlichste, was es im Deutschen gibt, ist der Ausdruck

> Sehnsucht nach dem Süden

Wobei vorausgesetzt wird, dass Mitteleuropa der aktuelle Aufenthaltsort ist – in [Namibia, wo auch Deutsch gesprochen wird](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/479/wird-deutsch-auch-ausserhalb-von-deutschland-osterreich-und-der-schweiz-gesproche), wird man diesen Ausdruck wohl weniger verwenden. ;-)

Comment: Aber ich kann's doch sehen? Hier?

Comment: Sehnsucht nach dem Süden klingt überhaupt nicht Deutsch in meinen Ohren. Es klingt mehr als hätte das ein nicht Muttersprachler übersetzt. Südlandslust hingegen klingt sehr idiomatisch.

Answer (score 12):

Natürlich ist *Südlandslust* ein »echtes« und »richtiges« Wort, und es existiert auch. Allein auf dieser Seite hier kann man es rund zehnmal lesen.

Es ist eine Zeichenkette mit klar erkennbarem Anfang und Ende, besteht ausschließlich aus lateinischen Buchstaben, und lässt sich eindeutig als ein Kompositum aus drei Bestandteilen (plus einem Fugenlaut) identifizieren.

Diese drei Bestandteile wiederum ergeben gemeinsam in der gegebenen Reihenfolge dem ganzen Wort eine ganz bestimmte, leicht erfassbare Bedeutung, insbesondere wenn das Wort in einem Kontext verwendet wird, der diese Bedeutung untermauert, wie z.B.:

> Freja und Erik packte die *Südlandslust*, und so flogen sie nach Tunesien.

*Südlandslust* steht in keinem Wörterbuch. Das trifft aber auch z.B. auf *Gitarrensaite* und *Windelbox* zu, weil die meisten Komposita nicht im Duden stehen.

Es ist neu und wurde bisher kaum verwendet, aber auch Wörter wie *Gasbeton*, *E-Mail* und *Grexit* waren mal völlig unbekannt.

Auch nach längerem Überlegen fällt mir kein stichhaltiges Argument ein, das dem Wort *Südlandslust* seinen Status als echtes und richtiges deutsches Wort aberkennen könnte.

Man könnte vielleicht noch diskutieren, ob das Fugen-s zwischen *Land* und *Lust* sein muss, jedoch ohne darauf eine klare Antwort zu erhalten. Denn auch z.B. den Advent(s)kalender gibt es mit und ohne Fugen-s.

Unter den bereits etablierten Wörtern ist »Fernweh« am ähnlichsten, wobei hier aber der Bezug zum Süden fehlt.

Comment: Absolut richtig. Es ist mir ein Rätsel, woher der Glaube kommt, neue Wörter müssten zuerst durch irgendein Geheimkomitee genehmigt werden, bevor man sie verwenden darf. Wenn mir ein so griffiges und unmittelbar verständliches Wort wie *Südlandslust* selber einfällt, dann verwende ich es natürlich auch.

Comment: Natürlich ist das ein richtiges und korrektes Wort und gefallen tut's mir auch. Allzu gebräuchlich dürfte es nicht sein und der Duden kennt es auch nicht. Wenn unsere Sprache allerdings seit Anbeginn der Zeiten keine bis dahin unbekannten Wörter akzeptiert hätte, wäre sie heute etwas karg......

Comment: @tofro: Darauf, dass nicht alles im Duden steht was häufig verwendet wird, habe ich mit den Beispielen »*Gitarrensaite*« und »*Windelbox*« bereits hingewiesen. Den Schluss »*Es steht nicht im Duden, also ist es nicht allzu gebräuchlich*« sollte man daher lieber nicht ziehen.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

Das Wort `Südlandslust` (beachte das `ü`) ist mir nicht bekannt. Es gibt aber ein sehr schönes deutsches Wort, das allgemein die Sehnsucht nach Reisen und der Fremde ausdrückt:

> Fernweh

Es setzt sich aus den Wörtern `Ferne`, also Weite oder Entfernung, und `Weh`, was so viel wie Schmerz bedeutet, zusammen. Analog dazu wird übrigens mit

> Heimweh

ausgedrückt, dass man sich nach seiner Heimat sehnt bzw. seine Heimat vermisst.

Comment: Fernweh bezieht sich aber auf Kamtschatka oder auf Finnland ebenso. Daher halte ich die Antwort für daneben - auch wenn sie meinen Verdacht, es müsste sich um Südlandslust handeln, bestärkt. Sie sollte ein Kommentar sein.

Comment: Dass sich Fernweh nicht nur auf den Süden bezieht, habe ich in meiner Antwort erwähnt. Der Fragesteller hat sich nach einem "ähnlichen" Wort erkundigt für dieses "deutsche Phänomen". Für mich kommt das Wort *Fernweh* am nächsten an die Bedeutung heran, da es das Wort *Südlandslust* meines Wissens nicht gibt. Ich verstehe auch deinen Kommentar nicht ganz. Bei was müsste es sich deinem Verdacht nach um Südlandslust handeln?

Comment: Nun, um ein Fernweh, welches vom Norden, Westen oder Osten nicht gestillt werden kann.

Comment: @userunknown Ein Kommentar nach acht Jahren ist vielleicht ungewöhnlich ;-) "Fernweh" ist eine Wortschöpfung von Fürst Pückler-Muskau (ja genau, nach ihm wurde das berüchtigte Fürst-Pückler-Eis benannt). Pückler bereiste Nordafrika (Algerien bis Ägypten), den Sudan, die Türkei und Griechenland. Das ursprüngliche Fernweh bezieht sich also nicht auf Kamtschatka oder Finnland. Das Wort hat aber Karriere gemacht- nach heutigem Sprachgebrauch gilt es für die ganze Welt.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Dass es eine Wortschöpfung Pücklers ist und Pückler selbst nur die von Dir aufgezählten Länder bereist hat beweist allerdings nicht, dass er das Wort nur für genau diese Länder oder allgemein für Länder des Südens verstanden wissen wollte, noch weniger, dass es von anderen so verstanden und gebraucht wurde.

Answer (score 0):

Wie so oft hilft Google und man findet folgenden [Text](https://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/krahwinkel-6848/7), aus dem ich zitiere:

...
So recht südländisch ging es hier zu. Und wälscher Süden waren die Bauten, die etwas unsauber aussehenden Gassen und Läden . . . wälscher Süden war der Zauber, der inmitten einer engen öden Gasse plötzlich einen romantischen Winkel erstehen ließ oder große farbige Klexe . . . hervorgerufen durch Wäsche, die man von dem einen Haus zu dem gegenüberliegenden aufgespannt hatte und die von lauer **Südlandslust** bewegt leise und geheimnisvoll wehte. ...

... Es war die Heiterkeit des **Südlandes**, die mich gefangen nahm. ...

... Und wenn sich der eine oder andere **Südlandswanderer** in Rovereto aufhielt, so mußte es eine besondere Passion sein.  ...

Es handelt sich um einen Auszug aus dem Buch

*Krähwinkel. Lustige Kleinstadtgeschichten. Leipzig: Staackmann 1918, 315 S.*

von Rudolf Heinrich [Greinz](https://orawww.uibk.ac.at/apex/uprod/f?p=TLL:2:0::::P2_ID:207). Das Buch ist übrigens noch [erhältlich](https://tredition.de/autoren/rudolf-greinz-10001/kraehwinkel-hardcover-29591/), auch [antiquarisch](https://www.booklooker.de/B%C3%BCcher/Rudolf-Greinz+Kr%C3%A4hwinkel-Lustige-Kleinstadtgeschichten/id/A027Fn6301ZZX).

Der Verfasser hat sich hier als Wortschöpfer betätigt. Ich finde das gelungen. Auch das als Alternative genannte "Fernweh" ist eine (nur wenig ältere) Wortschöpfung, wohl von Fürst [Pückler](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernweh) ca. 1835. Im Gegensatz zur "Südlandslust" ist das "Fernweh" in den allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch übergegangen.

PS. Beim nochmaligen Lesen des Textes beschlich mich der Verdacht, dass es sich um einen Druckfehler handelt. Besser würde "von lauer **Südlandsluft** bewegt" passen. Doch egal, Südlandslust finde ich charmant. Es erinnert ein wenig an "Wanderlust". Und dieses Wort hat es immerhin bis ins [Englische](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanderlust_(2012_film)) geschafft.

Und zum Abschluss noch ein bisschen Südlandslust aus lange vergangenen [Tagen](https://newspapers.library.in.gov/cgi-bin/indiana?a=d&d=IT18981225.1.8):

[image]

Man muss zugeben, dass das Fraktur-"f" leicht mit einem Fraktur-"s" verwechselt werden kann. Aber in den USA hat man vermutlich bessere OCR-Software als in Deutschland ;-)

Comment: Lustigerweise scheint die OCR-Software von allen schwierigen Wörtern ausgerechnet das richtig erkannt zu haben und nicht etwa das "spannte" ^^. Nichtsdestotrotz ist die Lust hier, wie du schon schreibst, wohl nur ein Druckfehler der es in die Übertragung bei Gutenberg geschafft hat.

Comment: @mtwde Dazu passt, dass die "Lufthansa" immer  wieder mal als "Lusthansa" verhohnepipelt wird. Hat aber eher nichts mit OCR zu tun ;-)

Comment: Interessant wäre auch, welche Variante sich in der Neuauflage des Textes von Greinz findet. Kaufen werde ich es aber nicht ;-)