# Fragen zu 'die Konfliktscheu'

Tags: noun

Wer Konflikten aus dem Weg geht, ist konfliktscheu. Gibt es in eurem aktiven/passiven Wortschatz ein Substantiv zum Adjektiv, *die Konfliktscheu*? Duden, OWID & Wahrig kennen es nicht, DWDS nicht als Lemma, aber immerhin in einer Belegstelle aus dem Korpus ("Komponente"). dict.cc hingegen kennt es und bietet engl. *conflict avoidance* sowie schwed. *konflikträdsla*; Pons kennt es ebenfalls und übersetzt mit *fear of conflict*.

Retrograde Suchläufe in drei Datenbanken ergeben bestenfalls eine Handvoll Nomen, darunter verblüffende wie *die Ehescheu* und *die Weiberscheu*, jedoch keine *Konfliktscheu*.

Eine Suche mit der Suchmaschine meines Vertrauens liefert einige, aber nicht beeindruckend viele Fundstellen für *die Konfliktscheu*: DIE ZEIT (1969 & ca. 2000), SPIEGEL (1969, 1977 & 1978), FAZ (2010), DW (2013). Ansonsten kommt die Nominalisierung vor in einem undatierten Artikel einer bayerischen Unternehmensberatung, einer Abschlussarbeit über Konfliktmanagement (2011) an der Universität Zürich, einer Dissertation (2008) an der Ruhr-Universität Bonn sowie auf Blogs, in Kommentaren und auf der World Socialist Web Site. Das nennt man dann wohl Bandbreite.

Was denkt ihr? Ist oder war die *Konfliktscheu* ein Wort, das nie so 'richtig' existiert hat, weil es eher von individuell-kreativem Umgang mit Sprache zeugt(e)? Oder hat es sich nicht gegen *Konfliktvermeidungsstrategie* durchgesetzt, das die psychologische Analyse ja gleich mitliefert? Haben die aktuellen einsprachigen Wörterbücher etwas - wenn auch nicht Hochfrequentes - verpasst? Oder getilgt? Findet ihr Sätze wie *Die Konfliktscheu der Kanzlerin ist nicht zu übersehen.* oder *Er zeichnet sich durch Konfliktscheu aus.* unauffällig, leicht verständlich, oder müsst ihr sozusagen zweimal lesen?

Comment: Ähnliche Frage zu einem anderen Wort: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1324/ist-südlandslust-ein-echtes-wort-gibt-es-ein-echtes-wort-für-diese-idee/

Comment: Was es nicht gibt, ist "Scheue", was man bisweilen hört.

Comment: @tofro Dann wird es Zeit, dass es eingeführt wird. Zumindest wird *Konfliktscheue* als Nomen verwendet, wie man bei Google Suchergebnissen sehen kann. Mir kam das auch als erstes in den Sinn, aber ich bin im schwäbischen aufgewachsen und wir können bekanntlich kein deutsch.

Comment: @Javatasse Tja, ich *befürchte*, das "Scheue" ein süddeutscher Regionalismus ist. Der Duden kennt nur "Scheu".

Answer (score 8):

Die Frage, ob es ein bestimmtes Wort gibt oder nicht, wird hier immer wieder gestellt, und die Antwort ist immer dieselbe:

Es gibt keine Behörde und auch keine andere Stelle, die deutsche Wörter amtlich absegnet. Mit anderen Worten: Es gibt keine offizielle Liste der deutschen Wörter.

Es gibt nur den Sprachgebrauch der Muttersprachler. Und hier ist die Sache relativ klar:

**Wenn ein Wort verwendet und verstanden wird, dann existiert dieses Wort ganz offensichtlich.** Dazu muss es in keinem Verzeichnis aufscheinen.

Dabei bedeutet »verstehen«: Eine Person spricht das Wort (in einem bestimmten Kontext) aus oder schriebt es nieder, und eine andere Person ist ohne große Probleme in der Lage, diesem Wort in ebendiesem Kontext eine Bedeutung beizumessen, die der Bedeutung, die der Sprecher/Autor im Sinn hatte, so nahe kommt, dass es legitim ist, davon auszugehen, dass Hörer/Leser und Sprecher/Autor dasselbe meinen.

---

Die in der Frage genannten Sätze

> Die Konfliktscheu der Kanzlerin ist nicht zu übersehen.
>   Er zeichnet sich durch Konfliktscheu aus.

empfinde ich als leicht verständlich und unauffällig. Da muss man nichts zweimal lesen.